# how should a join table controller associations be pluralized in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a `clients` table and a `workers` table that are joined with a `clients_workers` table. The join table has some additional columns so I have a controller for the join table

In my `ClientsController` I have the following

```
has_many :client_workers
has_many :workers, through: clients_workers
```

Is this the correct way to pluralize my `has_many` associations?

Answer (score 2):

Your `Client` model should have those lines not `ClientsController`

```
has_many :client_workers
has_many :workers, through: clients_workers
```

You should also have model classes for `ClientWorker` and `Worker`

Answer (score 1):

You can do nested `has_many` in Rails 3.1 or higher.

**client.rb**

```
class Client
  has_many :clients_workers
  has_many :workers, through: :clients_workers
end
```

**clients_worker.rb**

```
class ClientsWorker
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :worker
end
```